# Jenkins shared library: How to run code from a python module contained in a package?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I want to run a python script as part of a jenkins pipline triggered from a github repo. If I store the script directly in the repo itself, I can just do `sh 'python path/to/my_package/script.py'` which work perfectly. However since I want to use this from multiple pipelines from multiple repos, I want to put this in a jenkins shared library.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402263/can-i-create-shared-library-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-other-language-than-groovy) which suggested storing the python file in the `resources` directory and copying it to a temp file before use. That only works if the script is one standalone file. Unfortunately, mine is a package with multiple python files and imports between them, so thats a no go. I also tried to copy the entire folder containing the python package from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170409/how-to-load-files-from-resources-folder-in-shared-library-without-knowing-their), which suggests getting the location of the library with

```java
import groovy.transform.SourceURI
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

class ScriptSourceUri {
    @SourceURI
    static URI uri
}
```

but its gives me the following error:

```
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.net.URI create java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

It seems that some additional permissions are required, which I don't think I'll be able to acquire (its a shared machine).

So? Does anyone know how I can run a python package from jenkins shared library? Right now the only solution I can think of is to manually recreate the directory structure of the python package, which is obviously very messy and non-generic.

PS: There is no particular reason for using the python script over writing the same script in groovy. Its just that the python script is well tested, well understood and well supported. Rewriting the whole thing in groovy just isn't feasible right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://host:8080/jenkins/scriptApproval/ page of your Jenkins installation and approve the request for your scripts, please see below:-

[image]

And follow the [link](https://bart.jakubowski.in/2019/04/15/jenkins-script-approvals/) for more information.